# Is there a tool were one can view the latest manuscript abstracts for economics?

Tags: database, email, information-management, rss

I know an economics Professor who has to go through a daily struggle to view economics abstracts.  Like most university professors engaged in research, he likes to keep up to date on what the most current research is in his field.  The Professor subscribes to several of the most major econ journal's email lists.  Every day he gets several emails that show about 20 abstracts per email of the latest papers published.  He likes to read the abstracts on his mobile device while he is waiting for something and then revisit the best abstracts later on his desktop to read their full text PDFs.

It is very frustrating to him that he has to search through a bunch of emails to find the manuscript abstracts (rather than being able to look through a clean list of the latest abstracts).  He often reads the abstracts on his phone when he is free, and if he sees an abstract he wants to save so that he can read the full paper later on his desktop, he has no easy way to do that - he has to record the title of the abstract in another note taking application.  He would much prefer to be able to save the abstract to a list of favorites that he can view on his desktop.

According to him, most professors in economics in the US have this problem.  How can an economics Professor easily view abstracts from the latest research from economics journals and how can they save some abstracts to view later?  Does a mobile app exist for this purpose?

Comment: Hi. Have you tried using something like Google Scholar, Scopus, or Research Gate? I suggest you also search the Academia forum https://academia.stackexchange.com e.g. https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/121933/equivalents-of-pubmed-in-other-fields/122904#122904

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the Android App ["Researcher - More Than 9,000 Academic Journals"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.fusetech.stackademia) by Google Commerce Ltd, and then you'll get plenty of notifications, from any journal, and how you want these notifications.